# Regular expression trouble

Tags: regex, escaping, character

I've been struggling with getting a working regular expression for a little project of mine. Can anyone help me with a regex that matches anything inside `<>` symbols, but only when they are not preceded by a \ symbol?

For example:

```
<Escaped characters \<\> are right in the middle of this sentence.>, <Here is another sentence.>
```

Must match

```
1: Square brackets \<\> are right in the middle of this sentence.
2: here is another sentence.
```

So far I've managed

```
/<([^\\][^>]*?)>/ig
```

but that gives

```
1: Escaped characters \<\
2: Here is another sentence.
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Indent the code by 4 spaces or use the code button on the editor with the text you want to display as typed highlighted.

Comment: I have fixed the markup as far as I found problems. Please take a look at the source code to see what I've done (follow the edit link), and check whether there is any missing place that should be marked as code. You can then also delete your comments.

Comment: Couldn't find the edit buttons, lol. Thank you for being so patient.
First time using the site, does it show? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crimson's answer is not working for me in testing it in the [Regex Powertoy](http://regex.powertoy.org/) using `<Escaped characters \<\> are right in the middle of this sentence.>, <Here is another sentence.>` as the test but this (seems) to work:

`/<(?<!\\<).*?>(?<!\\>)/gi`

Gives me two matches:
`<Escaped characters \<\> are right in the middle of this sentence.>` and `<Here is another sentence.>`

**Edit**:  I took a look at the string Gumbo said did not match.  I don't have any problems matching it in regex.powertoy.org:

[alt text http://img362.imageshack.us/img362/3227/regexpowertoyorg.png](http://img362.imageshack.us/img362/3227/regexpowertoyorg.png)

In testing I did change the original posted regex to: **`/(?<!\\)<(.*?)(?<!\\)>/gi`** which is more efficient (less probes).

Also I notice in the output of regex.powertoy.org that the forth string (`\<hello <match\<this\>> but not this\> looks odd... the printed replacement is just`match`but the match detail clearly shows that the match is correct;`match\`.  But I also notices that the first and third test string replacements don't print the "``" escaping the angle brackets.  After a bit (but not exhaustive) playing around I think that this is an issue with the display of the text via javascript, the escaped angle brackets don't print the escape char, and non-empty angle brackets don't get printed at all.  I think this is due to the javascript seeing it as HTML.  So; I think this regex is working correctly.  But you should test it offline.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
/<((?:[^\\>]+|\\.)*)>/
```

Comment: Works nicely.  Less probes than mine.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are look-behind operators. Read about them here:

http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/07/01/regexps.html

And here is the expression you need:

```
/<(?!<\\).*>(?!<\\)/
```

As the * operator above is greedy, it should include any escaped angle brackets /< />

EDIT: I am assuming that you want escaped angle brackets to be matched and returned. If you want something different, please clarify - give a succinct example of a) the input string and b) the match to be returned

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm after the content inside each set of angle brackets.

Some example input: "<example>, <this is text>, <Oh god \<\> there are brackets in this one>".

This will output three different strings which I will access with backreferences. These are "example", "this is text" and "Oh god \<\> there are brackets in this one".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/<[^\\]([^>]+)>/
```

Comment: This is not checking for escaped angle brackets which need to be included.